# String to Integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a String with 2 Integers separated by a space. How do I assign this to 2 variables?

```
s = "1 2"
num1, num2 = int(s.split())
print(num1, num2)
```

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

This code above is not working: I am getting an error.

```
s = "1 2"
num1: int
num2: int
num1, num2 = s.split()
print(num1 + num2)
```

This also doesn't seem to work. I am getting 12 as output (String concatenation)

I do not want to use `int(num1)` everywhere in the code.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try this-

```
s = "1 2"
a, b = (int(i) for i in s.split())
# a = 1, b = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`

**Ex:**

```
s = "1 2"
num1, num2 = map(int, s.split())
print(num1, num2)
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 2)
```

Comment: You are welcome :)